# Better way to optimise IF statements

Tags: jquery

Is there a better way for me to optimise the following IF statements in jQuery?

I've had to edit the following code a couple of times and it would be nice if I could just plug in the necessary values in a nice array or something...

```
 $("#pmselect").change(function () {
        if ($("#pmselect option:selected").attr("class") == "null") {
            $('.avatar').hide();
            $('.pmpass').hide();
            $('.pmlogin').hide();
            $('#nullavatar').show();
        }
        if ($("#pmselect option:selected").attr("id") == "pm") {
            $('.avatar').hide();
            $('.pmpass').show();
            $('.pmlogin').show();
            $('#pmavatar').show();
        }
        if ($("#pmselect option:selected").attr("id") == "as") {
            $('.avatar').hide();
            $('.pmpass').show();
            $('.pmlogin').show();
            $('#asavatar').show();
        }
        if ($("#pmselect option:selected").attr("id") == "pn") {
            $('.avatar').hide();
            $('.pmpass').show();
            $('.pmlogin').show();
            $('#pnavatar').show();
        }
        if ($("#pmselect option:selected").attr("id") == "jm") {
            $('.avatar').hide();
            $('.pmpass').show();
            $('.pmlogin').show();
            $('#jmavatar').show();
        }
        if ($("#pmselect option:selected").attr("id") == "mh") {
            $('.avatar').hide();
            $('.pmpass').show();
            $('.pmlogin').show();
            $('#mhavatar').show();
        }
        if ($("#pmselect option:selected").attr("id") == "rh") {
            $('.avatar').hide();
            $('.pmpass').show();
            $('.pmlogin').show();
            $('#rhavatar').show();
        }
        if ($("#rmselect option:selected").attr("id") == "rm") {
            $('.avatar').hide();
            $('.pmpass').show();
            $('.pmlogin').show();
            $('#rmavatar').show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: switch/case statements??

Comment: Apart from the first `if`, you're making selections based on the `id` of the element. Using a `switch` for that is cleaner. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch. Also consider if all show/hide logic could be moved to separate functions so that you could separate it from your switch/if statements

Comment: Improving code that's already written and working -> http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @RaymondChen agree, codereview is a better location for this question

Comment: Codereview is indeed more appropriate (http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) however see my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could use switch/case, that way you could consolidate some things do be done in multiple cases...

```
switch( $("#pmselect option:selected").attr("id") ){
  case 'pm':
    //do stuff
    break;
  case 'xyz':
  case 'rh':
   //do stuff for xyz and rh
  case 'mh': 
   // do stuff for mh only
   break;
}
```

Comment: `switch( $("#pmselect option:selected").attr('id') ){` :)

Comment: Except that in the original code, the last `if` tests `#rmselect` not `#pmselect`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#pmselect").change(function () {
        $('.avatar').hide();
        if ($("#pmselect option:selected").attr("class") == "null") {
            $('.pmpass, .pmlogin').hide();
            $('#nullavatar').show();
        } else {
            var id = $("#pmselect option:selected").attr("id");
            $('.pmpass, .pmlogin').show();
            $('.pmlogin').show();
            $('#' + id + 'avatar').show();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `$("#rmselect option:selected")` in the last if expression to be a typo (with credit to eagle-eyed @RaymondChen), I think you will find the code simplifies to this :

```
$("#pmselect").change(function () {
    var opt = this[this.selectedIndex],
        isNull = $(opt).hasClass('null'),
        id = isNull ? 'null' : opt.id;
    $('.avatar').hide();
    $('.pmpass, .pmlogin')[isNull ? 'hide' : 'show']();
    $('#' + id + 'avatar').show();
});
```

Without an `if` in sight :)

If `$("#rmselect option:selected")` is not a typo, then the #rmselect condition will need to be handled separately.